# Need to debug between two separate pre-existing repos

Tags: python, git

I have to separate git Python repos that I have to debug between. In other words, one repo imports code from the other. For example, `file1.py` in `repo1` imports code from `repo2` via

```
import repo_2
```

and I have to debug both sets of code.  I have setup a separate debug branch under each repo and I switch to the respective debug branch when I am debugging, but I was hoping there was a technique I could use to automate or keep track of this. That way, I could debug in a more organized way.

I hope that made some sense.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Is your debugger unable to load source files in another project? Or do you want to checkout two related branches in otherwise independent repos? What is it you're doing manually that you want to automate?

Comment: Why do you have code in one repo that imports code from an entirely separate repo? Why not just have all source code in one repo? Or are you using Git submodules or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using two projects in two different git repos that have some sort of version connection to eachother, it's recommended that you use submodules for this. See:
http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html

Even if the text is somewhat negative against submodules... The other alternative is to use a subtree, that's the next chapter. Jugde yourself what you think fits your situation the best. From the information you've supplied so far I would say you want submodules.